# what is the meaning of series[series]

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I'm currently learning some machine learning, and using pandas, and in one of the examples they did this

```
# Get list of categorical variables
s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')
object_cols = list(s[s].index)

print("Categorical variables:")
print(object_cols)
```

I'm currently struggling to understand what happened when they did ***s[s].index*** , how does s[s] even possible? could someone help me please.
thanks in advance

this is a link of what I'm reading : https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/categorical-variables

Comment: read also about [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) since the series you have is already is a boolean , it can use boolean indexing on itself

Comment: I dont see a reason to do that. Maybe you mistyped it? I would imagine it would be something like: `object_cols = X_train[s].index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index Series by conditions, e.g. `myseries[myseries == 4]` would return the elements that are equal to `4`. In your case, if you have a boolean, these two expressions are identical:

```
myseries[myseries == True] 
myseries[myseries]
```

Therefore, in your example, you return the indices of all elements that are `True`:

```
myseries = pd.Series([True, False, True, False])
x = myseries[myseries] # returns Series: (0, True) (2, True)
x = x.index # returns [0,2]
```

In the context of your kaggle example these booleans are constructed by `s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')`, i.e. the code snippet that you posted gets the index of each training example that is of type `object`.

I would personally not recommend this shortcut, as it obscures the code unnecessarily and writing `s[s==True]` isn't too much work.